# Attach Leaf interface to EPG on Cisco ACI with Terraform

Tags: terraform, cisco

I'm trying to create an EPG on Cisco ACI using Terraform. EPG is created but Leaf's interface isn't attached.
The terraform synthax to attach Leaf interface is :

```
resource "aci_application_epg" "VLAN-616-EPG" {
  ...    
  relation_fv_rs_path_att      = ["topology/pod-1/paths-103/pathep-[eth1/1]"]
  ...
}
```

It works when I do it manually through ACI web interface or REST API

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this has been implemented yet.  If you look in the code for the provider there is no test for that attribute, and I find this line in the examples for the EPGs.  Both things lead me to believe it's not completed.  Also, that particular item requires an encapsulation with VLAN/VXLAN, or QinQ, so that would need to be included if this was to work.

```
  relation_fv_rs_path_att      = ["testpathatt"]
```

Probably the best you could do is either make a direct REST call (act_rest in the terraform provider), or use an Ansible provider to create it (I'm investigating this now).

Answer (score 0):

I ask to Cisco support and they send me this solution :

```
resource "aci_application_epg" "terraform-epg" {
   application_profile_dn = "${aci_application_profile.terraform-app.id}"
   name = "TerraformEPG1"
}

resource "aci_rest" "epg_path_relation" {
  path = "api/node/mo/${aci_application_epg.terraform-epg.id}.json"
  class_name = "fvRsPathAtt"

  content = {
    "encap":"vlan-907"
    "tDn":"topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/1]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with latest provider version is to do this:

```
 data "aci_physical_domain" "physdom" {
  name = "phys"
}

resource "aci_application_epg" "on_prem_epg" {
  application_profile_dn = aci_application_profile.on_prem_app.id
  name                   = "db"
  relation_fv_rs_dom_att = [data.aci_physical_domain.physdom.id]
}

resource "aci_epg_to_domain" "rs_on_prem_epg_to_physdom" {
  application_epg_dn    = aci_application_epg.on_prem_epg.id
  tdn                  = data.aci_physical_domain.physdom.id
}

resource "aci_epg_to_static_path" "leaf_101_eth1_23" {
  application_epg_dn  = aci_application_epg.on_prem_epg.id
  tdn  = "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/23]"
  encap  = "vlan-1100"
}
```